# How to run a batch command in java files without actually going to the batch file?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

So, it might be a noob question but am still stuck with it. I have a batch command in a batch file as:

```
@echo off
start "" /D "C:\UpworkUP" upwork.exe --args -url=chrome://crash  -disable-web-security -script-url=https://172.27.68.6/pre_alpha/
```

My doubt is how do I run this command from java itself without calling the batch file here. So per say, I do not want the batch file, I just need to run the command in it from java directly.

Comment: Preface command with `@` which does `echo off` on a line by line basis. Then pass your command line instead of the batchfile name. `cmd /c start "" /D "C:\UpworkUP" upwork.exe --args -url=chrome://crash  -disable-web-security -script-url=https://172.27.68.6/pre_alpha/`. Could probably be simplified to `C:\UpworkUP\upwork.exe --args -url=chrome://crash -disable-web-security -script-url=https://172.27.68.6/pre_alpha/`

Comment: the main problem I am facing is that of the inverted commas placement as a whole string here

Answer (score 0):

Making a batch file showing how arguments are being parsed.

```
@Echo %1
@Echo %2
@Echo %3
@Echo %4
@Echo %5
@Echo %6
@Echo %7
@Echo %8
@Echo %9
```

shows this result, how your arguments are being parsed most likely.

```
C:\Users\User>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\New Text Document.bat" --args -url=chrome://crash -disable-web-security -script-url=https://172.27.68.6/pre_alpha/
--args
-url
chrome://crash
-disable-web-security
-script-url
https://172.27.68.6/pre_alpha/
```

Which shows a errant space after `crash`. And maybe you neeed to escape `=` with a `^`, so `^=`. Fix first error, then see if you need to escape the equals.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("YOUR_COMMAND");
```

About [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)